# Change column values using iloc doesn't works

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a 'istrain' column in dataframe.
Some rows belonged to train data, some to test data.

So I tried as below.

```py
df['istrain'] = 0
df.iloc[:train_len,:]['istrain'] = 1
```

But it didn't work.

I solved my problem by changing the code as below, but I still want to know why the above method is wrong. It is also good to suggest a better way. Thank you for your answer.

```py
df['istrain'] = 0
df.iloc[:train_len,data.columns.get_loc('istrain')] = 1
```

Comment: Please refer to [Pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iloc` is integer-location based indexing.

`df.iloc[:train_len,:]['istrain']` returns a view and due to performance reasons the result is inherently unpredictable. It is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). (same applies for `df[:train_len]['istrain']`

The correct way of using it to use `df.columns.get_loc('istrain')` get the column location as integer and so use it directly inside `iloc` and update the value.

However a much better way to handle such situations is to use label-location based indexe `loc`

`df.loc[:train_len,'istrain'] = 1`

Comment: To use iloc, i had to change the code in the same way as df.iloc[:train_len -1, :]. I thought it wasn't intuitive. But if the problems I mentioned occur, I think this would be better. Thanks.